# Create column with group affiliations in R

Tags: r, grouping

Lets say I have a dataframe with column "a" and I want to add a column "b" that contains the group affiliation for a specified Interval.
I could use `cut` and `classIntervals` and solve this creating a function like this:

```
    library(classInt)
    df<-data.frame(a=c(1:120))
    function.group.data<-
                    function(my.data,my.method,my.number){
                           cut(my.data,
                               breaks=data.frame(classIntervals(my.data,  
                                                                method=my.method,
                                                                n=my.number)[2])[,1]
                                ,include.lowest=T)
    }
    df$b<-function.group.data(df$a,"quantiles",10)
```

But this has some limitations. For example in column b the group names are kind of unpretty written down like this `[1,12.9]`. For plotting purposes I would rather prefer them to be `01-12.9` ore something like this.

Also I'm pretty convinced that there is some built-in function in R and I won't have to invent something new. Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Are u sing `classIntervalls` or `classIntervals` ? and can you add the corresponding package please?

Comment: `classIntervals`...just edited it. thx.

Comment: So the package is `classInt`?

Comment: yes the package is `classInt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can format the labels of `cut` function. labels are constructed using "(a,b]" interval notation. But using `gsub` and some regular expression you can format your cut output. For example:

```
library(classInt)
x <- 1:120
b <- gsub('\\((.*)[,](.*)\\]','0\\1-\\2', 
          cut(x,classIntervals(x,10,'quantile',dataPrecision=2)$brks))
b <- as.factor(b)      ## because gsub returns a character
droplevels(head(b))    ## to remove extra levels(just for display here)
[1] <NA>    01-12.9 01-12.9 01-12.9 01-12.9 01-12.9
Levels: 01-12.9
```

Comment: thanks for the workaround...I thought maybe there would be an easier option since this is such a standart task for plotting numerical data, but seems like no one knows...  :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`levels(df$b) <- gsub('([^0-9]*)((?<=\\[|\\()[0-9\\.]*),([0-9\\.]*).*','\\2-\\3',levels(df$b),perl=T)`

EDIT: A prettier regex

`levels(df$b) <- gsub('.(.*),(.*).','\\1-\\2',levels(df$b),perl=T)`